# MODX: How to retrieve name of user who created resource?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am using getResources to display blog entries. For each entry I want to display the name of the user who created the resource.

I can retrieve their ID using placeholder `[[+createdby]]` but I don't know how to get their name.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a MODX Revolution output filter called `userinfo` that you can user on your placeholder like this:

`` [[+createdby:userinfo=`fullname`]] ``

Find out more about and other output filters here in the docs: [MODX Input and Output Filters](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/customizing-content/input-and-output-filters-(output-modifiers))